# How to set recyclerView item offset from percentage of visible item height in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

We are getting the index of the item and visible height percentage to show for the item as below:

[image]

As shown in the image, from the server, we are getting `index` **1** with `visiblePercentage`  **20** which means, show 2nd item (index 1) 20%. I know the method `linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset` but it requires `offset`. How can we convert percentage into offset?

Also, the `visiblePercent` is coming as `double` like **20.456** whereas the `offset` is an `int` value, which means, there can be **some** difference.

So, if there is a way to use the `double` to avoid loss of decimal part, it will be more accurate.

Comment: I'm sure you know that in order to calculate 20% of something, you need to know 100% (the height of the list item View). Do all the list items have the same height?

Comment: Yes @Bo macht Blau, All the list items have the same height